# the whole list goes to the same page flutter

Tags: arp, nt

[code photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0YKF.png)

[Video Link](https://www.veed.io/view/f41d5334-6253-45ab-872b-f6575e9b56e5?sharingWidget=true&panel=)

the whole list goes to the same page and i can't change it please help

I want to make each Soru[index] list start with different questions according to the index. Thus, there will be many questions related to January and those who use the application will solve the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.